# How check how many custom fields has a Wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

How to check how many custom fields has a post, I don't want retrieve any value but I need to find out how many custom fields has a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php
    // get only the keys as you only need the number
    $cfields = get_post_custom_keys($post_id);
    // num_cfields will store the number of custom fields
    $num_cfields = count($cfields);
?>
```

There's also [get_post_custom](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) as well as [get_post_custom_values](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_values)

Comment: It doesn't work for me - echo $num_cfields returns always '1' no matter how many custom fields post has, I tried  get_post_custom et_post_custom_values, same result.

Comment: It works perfectly for me

<?php echo count(get_post_custom_keys($post->ID)); ?>

Comment: count(cfields); should be count($cfields);

Comment: Indeed! Thanks, @Dev!